# Angular JS , go to different state with $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I need some help. I am new with angular.

I want to go to another state in another folder from current folder.
For example :

I have two different folder , A and B. They have config.ui-routing
But the problem is , how to $state.go to Folder A when i declared the $state.go in folder B.

Here is my code:

```
//UI routing config in folder B
$stateProvider
     .state('login',{
        url:"/login",
        views:{
            "main":{templateUrl: prefixPath+"login.html"}  
   },
        resolve: loadSequence('loginController')
})
```

while my controller location folder is in folder A.
Here is my controller code:

```
// state in folder A Controller
$state.go('login');
```

The errors said:

> Error: Could not login' from state

Can you guys help me ?

Comment: It's marked with tag 'php', but you're saying about angular. Looks strange.

Comment: It should not matter in which folder your controller is, if you have included that in head of HTML. You also need to see if the file where `$state.go` has called is loaded after the files in which you have declared that

Comment: check with f12 tools in chrome under network tab if you get redirected

Answer (score 1):

This very often happens if we declare two modules without creating dependency.

There is [a broken example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mwMk3bevdRlWnFJAD8rY?p=preview)

The **`login`** module in `login.js`:

```
var app = angular
  .module('MyLoginPart', [
    'ui.router' 
  ])
.config(['$stateProvider',
    function ($stateProvider) {

        // States
        $stateProvider
          .state('login', {
              url: "/login",
              templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
          })
     }
])
```

And this is the main module (used as ng-app)

```
var app = angular
  .module('MyApp', [
    // missing dependency on above
    'ui.router' 
  ])
```

when we navigate to the 'login' state, we get:

> Error: Could not resolve 'login' from state ''

There is a fixed, [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/SHVtxPdq8PsZ5blQPvVk?p=preview), where we declare dependency:

```
var app = angular
  .module('MyApp', [
    'MyLoginPart',
    'ui.router' 
  ])
```

And this is working:

```
<a ui-sref="login">
```

Answer (score -1):

i do not have any idea, actually i do not understand Sir Radin's answer, so i try to make the hardcode,

```
window.location.href = '../admin/login';
```